# How to reduce Magento Product Prices reindexing time for 1M product with 5K customer group?

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

How to reduce Magento Product Prices reindexing time for 1M product with 5K customer group?

I'm working with magento 1.9.2 website for a manufacture company which has over `1M product (each product have 5+ customer grouping price and trier pricing)` and `5k+ customer group`.

I did all the basic performance measures.

Buyed a dedicated server, now website performs good except the indexes.
while reindexing `'Product Prices'` takes one or more days (some times it never stopped) and pricing is not being updated properly in frontend (note: prices updated regularly through api).

So i planned to store the pricing data's to my custom table and i reflected this to frontend.
Even all the products stored all the prices (0.00) in related tables (Magento tables).

This also takes too much time to re-indexing all.

***What I tried Previously?***

Truncated the price related tables.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
```

if i truncated the above table, then the product collection not showing in frontend.

***Now what i want to know?***

1. when truncated the above tables why the products not showing?
2. how to avoid this issues?
3. where i go to remove the join query to remove the pricing related collections?

I am looking for permananet solutions for avoiding to store prices, customer prices and trier prices in magento db.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "re-indexing"? And what purpose does it serve?

Comment: @strawberry It simply queries your existing data and copies it to it's own tables.

Comment: The way we've worked with this (we run about 800k) is to avoid the api whenever possible, and instead work with the DB directly, most updates just need a re-cache instead of a re-index, and it means you can't really use the flattened tables, but if your catalog is that big, you probably aren't using it anyway.